# Load dataset from "R" package using data(), assign it directly to a variable?

Tags: r, dataframe

How do you load a dataset from an R package using the `data()` function, and assign it directly to a variable without creating a duplicate copy in your environment?

Put simply, can you do this without creating two identical dfs in your environment:

```
> data("faithful") # Old Faithful Geyser Data from datasets package

> x <- faithful 

> ls() # Now I have 2 identical dfs - x and faithful - in my environment
[1] "faithful" "x" 

> remove(faithful) # Now I've removed one of the redundant dfs
```

**Try 1:**

My first approach was to just assign `data("faithful")` to `x`. But `data()` returns a string. So now I have the df `faithful` and the character vector `x` in my environment.

```
> x <- data("faithful")
> x
[1] "faithful" # String, not the df "faithful" from the datasets package

> ls()
[1] "faithful" "x"
```

**Try 2:**
Tried to get a little more sophisticated in my second attempt.

```
> x <- get(data("faithful")) # This works as far as assignment goes

> ls() # However I still get the duplicate copy
[1] "faithful" "x"
```

A short note about my motivation for trying to do this. I have an R package with 5 very large data.frames - each having the same columns. I want to efficiently generate the same calculated columns on all 5 data.frames. So I want to use `data()` within a `list()` constructor to get the 5 data.frames into a list. Then I want to use `llply()` and `mutate()` from the `plyr` package to iterate over the dfs in the list and create the calculated columns for each df. But I don't want to have duplicate copies of the 5 large datasets sitting in my environment as this is within a Shiny App with a RAM limit.

---

**edit:**
I was able to use both of @henfiber's methods from his answer to figure out how to lazy-load entire data.frames into a named list.

The first command here works for assigning a data.frame to a new variable name.

```
# this loads faithful into a variable x. 
# Note we don't need to use the data() function to load faithful
> delayedAssign("x",faithful)
```

But I wanted to create a named list `x` with elements `y = data(faithful)`, `z=data(iris)`, etc.

I tried the below and it didn't work.

```
> x <- list(delayedAssign("y",faithful),delayedAssign("z", iris))
> ls()
[1] "x" "y" "z" # x is a list with 2 nulls, y & z are promises to faithful & iris
```

But I finally was able to construct a list of lazy-loaded data.frame objects in the following manner:

```
# define this function provided by henfiber
getdata <- function(...)
{
e <- new.env()
name <- data(..., envir = e)[1]
e[[name]]
}

# now create your list, this gives you one object "x" of class list
# with elements "y" and "z" which are your data.frames
x <- list(y=getdata(faithful),z=getdata(iris))
```

Comment: You could remove the data right after having it assigned to your list, something like `data( "faithful" ); x <- faithful; rm( faithful )`

Comment: @vaettchen that's definitely an option. Just wondering if there technically exists a way to skip loading the extra copy into the environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a helper function:

```
# define this function
getdata <- function(...)
{
    e <- new.env()
    name <- data(..., envir = e)[1]
    e[[name]]
}

# now load your data calling getdata()
x <- getdata("faithful")
```

Or using an anonymous function:

```
x <- (function(...)get(data(...,envir = new.env())))("faithful")
```

#### Lazy evaluation

You should also consider `lazy loading` your data adding `LazyData: true` in the DESCRIPTION file of your package.

If you use `RStudio`, after running `data("faithful")`, you'll see at the `Environment` panel that the "faithful" data.frame is called `"promise"` (another less common name is `"thunk"`) and is greyed out. That means that it is lazily evaluated by R and not still loaded into memory. You can even lazy load the `"x"` variable with the `delayedAssign()` function:

```
data("faithful")              # lazy load "faithful"
delayedAssign("x", faithful)  # lazy assign "x" with a reference to "faithful"
rm(faithful)                  # remove "faithful"
```

Still nothing has been loaded into memory yet

```
summary(x)                    # now x has been loaded and evaluated
```

Learn more about `lazy evaluation` [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lazy-evaluation).

Comment: Great edit! The edited code sounds really promising. I do use RStudio and noticed how `promise` magically turns into an object in memory even as I type the variable name on the command line or an open .R file. I'm working on a big refactor at the moment but once that's done I'll try your solution out.

Comment: Take your time and pls share your feedback - and your `shiny` app if it's not a company secret :)

Comment: Thank you. Your edit with `delayedAssign` was perfect. Although it doesn't really work for my idea of constructing a named list with values equal to the loaded datasets, it answers the question.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to do `data("faithful")` and `rm(faithful)`. I tried `delayedAssign("x", faithful)` without any context and it just worked...

Comment: @aashanand You're right! And since `delayedAssign()` all it does is to lazy `eval()` the expression in the second argument, then the following works also : `x <- eval(faithful)`. An that could be simply the answer to your original question (load `faithful` but assign to `x`).

Comment: Note however, that this will work only with datasets from installed packages and not with all methods `data()` supports, like loading files under the `data` subfolder in the current working directory. Also if there is a function named `faithful` in your current environment, then `x` will be assigned the function and not the dataset. That's why I prefer the first two solutions (with functions and temp environments) which avoid `namespace` conflicts, optionally combined with `delayedAssign()`

Comment: +1 for considering environment hierarchy within `search()`. As requested, [here's](https://aashanand.shinyapps.io/eurofootycharts) my app. Still needs some work, suggestions welcome.

Comment: Well done, I like the ranking evolution graph. I would like it even more if I could see the evolution not only per season, but also during the last `X` years.

Comment: Working on that. Also working on making the tooltips contain a lot more information.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a simple solution like this:

```
x <- list(y = datasets::faithful, z = datasets::iris )
```

Comment: This solution seems to be the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

I am simply using

```r
x <- get("faithful")
```

in a Shiny app of mine. `get` searches for an object by name and returns it.